# Cannot rsync Git objects

Tags: backup, git, rsync

I'm using rsync to backup my home directory to a Synology NAS. Everything works fine except Git objects:

```
$ rsync -avP $HOME me@server:/volume1/homes/me/

...

rsync: open(.git/objects/c8/f9ba8b537b0329a003b9a2c3585c5937bf6ec2) failed!!: Permission denied (13)

...
```

But:

```
$ ls -la .git/objects/c8/f9ba8b537b0329a003b9a2c3585c5937bf6ec2
-r--r--r-- 1 me me 627 Nov 13  2013 .git/objects/c8/f9ba8b537b0329a003b9a2c3585c5937bf6ec2
```

I don't understand what the problem is. I can access all the files, the repositories work and all other files are backed up just fine. What's so special in these Git object files?

Comment: What are the permission of the file/path on the other side where are you syncing?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in Synology's rsync: https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=34669

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour between two Ubuntu 17.04 machines: this is not a Synology specific bug

Comment: @Frédéric Grosshans That's weird. I got this fixed by updating the software of my Synology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this eventually fixed by updating the software of my Synology to the latest. Now rsync runs just fine (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).